# "Can't get a consistent path to setup script from installation directory"

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm using pip to install a package from a git repository:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow.git@master#egg=SpiffWorkflow-dev
```

The repo gets cloned without a problem, but installation fails with this message:

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package SpiffWorkflow
Installing collected packages: SpiffWorkflow
Running setup.py develop for SpiffWorkflow
 error: ("Can't get a consistent path to setup script from installation 
  directory", '/', '/home/fcorreia/venvs/myproj/src/spiffworkflow')
```

I have tried taking a look to the project's [setup.py](https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow/blob/master/setup.py), but without much success... Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the flag `-e` means "editable", and it is the same doing `python setup.py develop`, that creates a symbolic link from `<PACKAGE_NAME_LOWERCASE>` to your `site-packages` directory and not running an usual installation.

Looking at SpiffWorkflow's `setup.py` I can see where the problem relies:

```
srcdir = join(dirname(__file__), 'src')
setup(...,
      package_dir      = {'': srcdir})
```

It says that the package content is located at `src`, instead of `spiffworkflow` (what develop mode expects).

You can just drop the `-e` flag and be happy:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow.git@master#egg=SpiffWorkflow-dev
```

---

References:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/126
- http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#develop
- https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/177/setuppy-develop-

Comment: In case I'd like to keep ``-e``, so that I can point to my branch of SpiffWorkflow and do changes to that working copy directly, what would you say is the best solution? The first reference that you point to makes me think that the issue could be solved by adding ``srcdir`` to the python path, and that it could maybe be done as one of the first actions on setup.py. It doesn't seem a very elegant solution though...

Comment: I don't think adding `srcdir` to python path would work, since when you do `import spiffworkflow` python looks for a directory named `spiffworkflow` in your pythonpath, but what would exist is the name `src`. I don't know a solution to this problem, and I think it is a kind of "anti-pattern" about packaging naming the package directory to any other name but the `setup(name=XXX)` - maybe a pull request to the author would be good. Let me know if you find a better solution.

Comment: Is this still not fixed? I am running setuptools (35.0.2) but I still got this error. After moving out of src the issue is solved

Comment: I, too, am running into this when I my package in a src folder. The workaround I use is running `pipenv shell` to create a virtualenv, and then I'm able to run `pip install -e .` without error. I'm not sure why this works though.

Comment: I found out that if you put a blank pyproject.toml file in your folder, this error goes away.

Comment: Offtopic: `setup(name=XXX)` may be not needed for your everyday packages, but for namespace packages/extensions to main package where you must preserve original `__init__.py` of super-packages, there's no other way. BTW, see my solution to the "srcdir" problem.

Answer (score 9):

For future folk, if you're using an older version of setuptools on windows 10 and it looks like it has an extra slash, you need to update the python package 'setuptools' to get around this [windows 10 python bug](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1521)

you can update any number of ways, but one is `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: I upgraded PIP, but forgot to upgrade setuptools. Thanks for the reminder and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a `pyproject.toml` file in your package. I have no idea why this makes the error go away, but it works. This file is part of [PEP 518 "Specifying Minimum Build System Requirements for Python Projects"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

You can have your package in a `src` subfolder if you have a `pyproject.toml` in your project:

```
/src/yourpackage/__init__.py
/setup.py
/pyproject.toml
```

I have no idea why this works, but it makes the error message go away when you run `pip install -e .` to install the package in "editable" mode. The file doesn't even have to have anything in it, **it can be a blank file** and the error goes away.

(To figure this out, I found a working project that had its package stored under a `src` folder and kept deleting things until I got that error. This is clearly some bug in Pip. I have version 18.1 on Windows 10 for Python 3.7 on my machine.)

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was with `package_dir = {'': './src'}`: I have specified *path* to dir, rather than dir *name*, which for some reason worked fine with `setup.py bdist_wheel`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the followng structure for my project:

```
+-- project/
    +-- src/
    |   +-- project/
    |       +-- __init__.py
    +-- doc/
    +-- tests/
    +-- setup.py
    +-- ...
```

So basically, all python code in `/src/project`. This permits to avoid `project` to be directly imported from tests scripts or whatever.

`setup.py` content:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    ...
)
```

Now I want to pull all this one level below, so that the overall project can have different components, as follows:

```
+-- project/
    +-- backend/
    |   +-- src/
    |       +-- project/
    |           +-- __init__.py
    |
    +-- frontend/
    |   +-- ...
    |
    +-- doc/
    +-- tests/
    +-- setup.py
    +-- ...
```

So I got the error message as in OP when trying to `pip install -e .`, even after trying to fix all paths.

I solved it by following update in `setup.py`:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages('backend/src'),
    package_dir={'': 'backend/src'},
    ...
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, `https://github.com/quiver-team/torch-quiver/blob/main/setup.py`
I remove the `./` chars from the beginning of my package dir configuration.

```py
# package_dir = './srcs/python'
package_dir = 'srcs/python'
```

And I install it successfully.
refer to https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/3755

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33581196)